# How to disable the minimumInteractiveComponentSize in material3?

Tags: kotlin, compose-desktop, material3

By default, Compose Desktop puts a lot of spacing around anything that's clickable. Which makes sense on a phone, but not on a Desktop app, since we have a mouse.

In material2, I could disable that spacing:

```
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalMinimumInteractiveComponentEnforcement provides false) {
  // app content
}
```

In material3, that same API is available, but I still get a lot of spacing around things like an `IconButton`. I took a look at the `minimumInteractiveComponentSize` Modifier implementation, and it still uses that same property.

How do I disable the extra spacing in material3?